# Override full mysql table

Tags: mysql, memory-table

Recently I stuck with a problem such that mysql table with memory engine got full, and an insertion failed (really really long php script). I quickly got rid of it, by checking before I insert whether there's already many rows and deleting them

```
if (query("Select count(*) As c From my_table")['c'] > $N)
{
    query("Delete from my_table Order by ID Limit " . round($N/2));
}
```

But that doesn't feel cool. Actually, I want mysql to do it for me. Now, the question:
is there a standard alternative to AUTO_INCREMENT, but which would return not `LAST+1` every time, but `LAST+1 (mod N)`. And which would let to just override lines with old ID column value. Is there such mechanism, or I have to implement it myself?
Thank you.

Comment: auto_increment is intended to generate non-repeating sequential numbers. allowing overwrites would defeat their purpose.

Comment: @MarcB That's exactly why I need something else.

Comment: there's no standard alternative. you could probably fiddle something with a trigger, but you'd be better off leaving the increments alone, and simply DELETING the old x+1modN record. that way you guarantee unique IDs, and older ids are automatically removed.